# Kafka - not all consumers receive subscribed message

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, consumer

To generically publish messages using Kafka, I'm using the class name as the topic:

```
kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(object.getClass().getName(), new DomainObjectAdapter(object).toJsonString()));
```

And the consumers subscribe to the classes they are interested in:

```
    for(Object sub:_subscriptions)
        topics.add(sub.getClass().getName());
    _kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topics);
```

The problem is, only one of the consumers ever receive the subscribed to message.  My understanding is that kafka will assign a unique partition to each subscriber (if available).  I currently only have 2 subscribers and my kafka server.properties specified 4 partitions.  It appears that all consumers are reading from the same partition.  Perhaps Kafka is a poor choice for a service bus due to this apparent limitation.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Kafka consumer properties:

```
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", _settings.getEndpoint());
    properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    properties.put("group.id", "TestGroup");
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset","earliest");
```

Kafka producer properties:

```
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers",_settings.getEndpoint());
    properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Server properties (the only thing I changed from the default properties):

```
num.partitions=4
```

Note: I've also tried consumer settings as:

```
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", _settings.getEndpoint());
    properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put("auto.commit.interval.ms","1000");
    properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    properties.put("group.id", "testGroup");
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset","latest");
    properties.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
```

Comment: The suggestion provided by senseiwu didn't work, if anyone else has any other suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Perhaps Kafka isn't well suited for a generic messaging bus?

Comment: Are you sure you have 4 partitions? Could you describe one of your topics to check it: "bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic MY_TOPIC_NAME"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your consumers have the same consumer group (`group.id` property) then only one consumer from the group will receive the message. If you want all the consumers to receive the message, they need to have different `group.id`.

To check which consumers are bound to the partitions of the topic, you can use the following command

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server yourhost:9092 --group testGroup --describe
```

Comment: This worked!  For the consumers that I wanted to be broadcast recipients of a message I ensured that the group ID was unique for their subscription.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kafka by default uses [RangeAssignor](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html) as partition assignment strategy, which has the following characteristics:

> The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. For each topic, we lay
>   out the available partitions in numeric order and the consumers in
>   lexicographic order. We then divide the number of partitions by the
>   total number of consumers to determine the number of partitions to
>   assign to each consumer. If it does not evenly divide, then the first
>   few consumers will have one extra partition. For example, suppose
>   there are two consumers C0 and C1, two topics t0 and t1, and each
>   topic has 3 partitions, resulting in partitions t0p0, t0p1, t0p2,
>   t1p0, t1p1, and t1p2. The assignment will be: C0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0,
>   t1p1] C1: [t0p2, t1p2]

If you want more even distribution for small number of partitions, you could use 
[RoundRobinAssignor](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RoundRobinAssignor.html) by setting `partition.assignment.strategy`

Comment: The RangeAssignor sounds like what I want  However, I will try using the RoundRobinAssignor.

Comment: I added "partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor" to the server.properties file and it didn't have an effect on my issue.  That is, only one subscriber receives the published message.

Comment: Just to be clear for anyone reading this post, the solution suggested by senseiwu did not work for me.

Comment: `partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor` is a consumer config. Not sure whether setting it in `server.properties` works (never tried that way)

Comment: If even after using it as consumer config doesn't work, share more info such as how many topics are there in practice -- should be possible to work out then what is going wrong based on the documentation. You could also consider `StickyAssignor` or a custom partitioner in the worst case

Comment: I already specified how many topics....there are essentially infinite topics.  I am using the class name as the topic.

Comment: not sure..a bit puzzling t.b.h. If there are indeed only 2 consumers and 4 partitions, even `RangeAssignor` should give you what you want. In your qstn you wrote -  *It appears that all consumers are reading from the same partition.* How are you coming to that conclusion? If your consumers had formed a proper consumer group, it is impossible that all the consumers read from the same partition. One consumer can get multiple partitions, but a given partition will be assigned only to a single consumer. This is how Kafka guarantees ordering.